# writing a single sector into a dump binary file using vba

Tags: excel, vba, file-writing, hexdump, sector

I need to recursively update,  using excel vba, a dump binary file with a binary hex string 512 bytes long (1 sector).
As i wrote in title, this hex string has to be written into a given sector (for example, sector 100 ) so i need a function that can receive the position in input.
I only found the "put" instruction but it is not what i'm looking for.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

I tryed yo use put instruction but it doent fit to me. Dump file is quite big (5 GB) and put is too too slow.

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you have a read of [ask] and [mcve] please.  Specifically the "Help others reproduce the problem" part of the how to ask link.